# Single fullscreen application via remote desktop in headless vm

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, headless

I want to set up a virtual machine (kvm/qemu) that runs on a headless host. The guest should run a Linux system (preferebly Ubuntu Server) that runs a single non-headless application. This should be accessible via a remote desktop tool.

The key is I want to install/run as less of X11, etc. as possible.

This has been giving me (and other people) headache for some time now. I don't even know anymore what I've tried so far so I want to start from scratch.

I know this is kind of a general/big question but you guys are my last hope :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing something similar. the easiest way I can think of is to install X and the application, as well as the minimum dependencies, then use X forwarding to view the application.

On Linux/Mac it's as simple as ssh -X host app, and there are apps to do it from windows as well with a third-party application.

Comment: The problem with that would be that the application stops running if I close my SSH client. I want it to continue running even if I'm not looking at it.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend looking into [X11VNC](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/)